# Clarification on status code 304 and 200 (both from cache)

Tags: caching, status

[image]

[image]

I've got 2 images here which shows response headers of a page. The only difference is that the first image states directly that the (response code : 200)request was resolved directly from cache and it received no response from server while the 2nd image shows that (response headers : 304) it has 3 headers, Response Headers, Request Headers and the last one is Response Headers from Cache.

So for the first image, it's obvious that the server doesnt have a response that's why the browser loads the page from cache (which cache? Browser? server? Assuming you don't want to get the page from cache maybe because the session expires, is it possible to disable caching ). But for the 2nd image, does that mean that it was able to contact the server but since it doesn't have any changes in the page, the cache (cache from what? browser or server) was served to client?